# Extern "C" giving error "Linkage specification is not allowed" even after adding def. in header file?

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, java-native-interface

This is the code in my main.cpp file:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_SomefnHandling_Jni_1someInit (JNIEnv * env, jobject , jstring var1, jstring var2)
{
    //rest part of code in here
}
```

This is the definition in my main.h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
    #endif
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Someufnhandling_Jni_1someInit
        (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This program is taking 2 parameters from a java file and passing to my dll using jni interface but in this file I'm getting the error:

> Linkage specification is not allowed

I'm using VC++ to generate the DLL file and have tried to find same solution from SO but they all are mentioning just add def. in your header file. 
Even after doing so error still remains same.
Any Idea?

Comment: try putting the function definition in main.cpp inside extern "C" { } brackets instead of just putting the extern "C" on the same line

Comment: Tried already ... not working ...

Comment: Have you made a typo or a transcription error? The name of the function is different between the declaration and the definition, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: naah dat one is correct in code m trying to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed method I was calling in main function and put it outside of main and simply it started working like charm